# Radio button not passing value when submitted

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an UI where I use a radio button to select the gender. However, when I press submit to store the data to the database I only ever get a null value

This is the code:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="gender" 
                  value="{formBean.number}" 
                  layout="grid" 
                  columns="2"
                  required = "True"
                  requiredMessage="#{bundle.requiredGender}">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelMale}"  itemValue="Male"/>  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelFemale}" itemValue="Female" />  
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

What have I missed out?

Comment: And what does the generated HTML look like ?

Comment: All as it should do a correct two button radio with the male and female next to it

Comment: Inspect the HTML, does the radio buttons have a name

Comment: Did you look at its `value` attribute? Twice?

Comment: Yep value i forgot to put # infront of the {, such a simple mistake but have been driving me mad ! thanks guys for the second pair of eyes i needed